# Why cant I pass an element attribute to scope.$watch but i can pass a function that returns it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular2-directives

I wrote a directive watchId with the following code

```
.directive('watchId', function(){
 return {
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
   scope.$watch(function() { return elem.attr('id') }, function(newValue){
    if (newValue) {
     scope.loaded[newValue] = true
    }
   })
  }
 }
})
```

The above code works correctly but my question is why cant i just do `scope.$watch(elem.attr('id'), function(newValue) {`

I dont think it will be needed but here is a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leathan/w4nx76sq/2/) where Im playing with the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because elem is not a `$scope` field (but a service injected by angular) and that syntax is valid only for property under the `$scope` service.

You can consider it like a "shortcut".

for example

```
$scope.stuff = {}

$scope.$watch('stuff', function(newVal){
 //this is valid because stuff is a property of the $scope object
})
```

if the property you want to watch is not part of the `$scope` object you must register a function as tthe first argument that will be triggered every digest cycle to check for changes.

**why you need a function?**

the function you pass to the watcher is a closure and has access to the outer scope, that means all the outer scope variables including `elem`.

Comment: that helped me, now I see why `elem.attr('id')` wont work, but why does returning it from a function work? EDIT: i read the answer again and i think I get it, basically it needs a function to call and if you dont include one it defaults to the $scope?